# PL/SQL - How to use CASE in JOIN ON specific condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join, case

Could you please advise how can achieve below?

I'm joining below subquery (quote_history) with quote table (q.).

Just to note, I'm getting 2 rows for each quote_ref.

Currently it's joining by quote_ref, but I'd like to add CASE that if q.quote_description = 'XYZ' then join also on quote_history.rown = 1 (I want only 1st row in this case), else ignore this another AND (leave only by quote_ref)

eg. for q.quote_description = 'XYZ' I'd like to get something like

```
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT quote_ref
                     ,activity_date_key
                     ,quote_status_key
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quote_ref ORDER BY activity_date_key) rown
                     ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY quote_ref, quote_status_key)  max_rown
                      FROM [...]
                    ) quote_history
           ON    q.quote_ref = quote_history.quote_ref 
           AND  quote_history.rown = 1 --this is only when q.quote_description = 'XYZ'
```

but for other cases (q.quote_description <> 'XYZ') I want only

```
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT quote_ref
                     ,activity_date_key
                     ,quote_status_key
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quote_ref ORDER BY activity_date_key) rown
                     ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY quote_ref, quote_status_key)  max_rown
                      FROM [...]
                    ) quote_history
           ON    q.quote_ref = quote_history.quote_ref
```

Alternatively (but it's uglier solution I think) I can also get something like

```
JOIN [...] 
ON    q.quote_ref = quote_history.quote_ref 
AND IF q.quote_description = 'XYZ' THEN quote_history.rown in (1)
ELSE quote_history.rown in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
       ON  q.quote_ref = quote_history.quote_ref AND
           (quote_history.rown = 1 or q.quote_description <> 'XYZ')
```

Note:  This assumes that `q.quote_description` is never `NULL`.  The logic can be adjusted for this if necessary (otherwise it just complicates the idea).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to achieve, it's working fine for me
Edit: Yes, quote_description is never a NULL, these cases are excluded earlier in query